# Selecting middle part of a string / mySQL result with PHP or query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I am selecting a column from a mySQL table which has a value something like this:

```
<div class="article news group">
    <p class="news_info">18/10/12</p>
    <h2>Hello world!</h2>
    <p>ertwrt aerteartert</p>
    <p>ertaertert</p>
    <p>waertwertwertwaertweart</p>
</div>
```

I now need to only get the 3 p tags from this - so returning:

```
    <p>ertwrt aerteartert</p>
    <p>ertaertert</p>
    <p>waertwertwertwaertweart</p>
```

Is there an easy way to do this with php or will I need to use jQuery to remove the unwanted code.

Either way, any ideas how I would do it?

Comment: It's better to do it with PHP if it's unwanted.  No reason to send it to the client (more traffic) and then remove it.  PHP & regular expressions are what you need in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP

```
$html = '<div class="article news group">
    <p class="news_info">18/10/12</p>
    <h2>Hello world!</h2>
    <p>ertwrt aerteartert</p>
    <p>ertaertert</p>
    <p>waertwertwertwaertweart</p>
</div>';

preg_match_all('~(<p>.+?</p>)~', $html, $match);

echo implode("\n", $match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be help for your needs : http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

If the html you are processing is more complicated than the example you might want to consider QueryPath (http://querypath.org/)

It would be overkill for your example but can be quite useful for this type of manipulation.